# Custom membership provider get current login user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, membership

I have little problem, I implement my own membership provider and it works fine. I added userid to articles by this code in controller:

```
[HttpPost, Authorize, ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Vytvorit(Article newArticle)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid){
                    if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    return View(newArticle);
                newArticle.User.UserID = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

            repo.Save(newArticle);
            return RedirectToAction("Zobrazit", new {id=newArticle.ArticleID});
            }
            return View(newArticle);
        }
```

and it was working but now after many changes (in another controllers, models and so) I tried and there is some problem with membership.getuser returns null.

I tried to google it and I found that there might be problem that  authenticated user can't be found in the Membership datasource. But I dont know how to fix it.

Thanks

EDIT:
[MyMembershipProvider](http://www.clipboard.cz/4skxn)

Comment: Can you show your custom membership provider code?

Comment: I added all my code from membershipprovider, hope it helps

Comment: `MyMembership` does not contain a method for `GetUser` that accepts zero parameters from what I can tell. There is only one implementation that looks to accept a `string` and a `bool`. So, maybe you copied and pasted old code, but I can't see how your controller even compiles yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if it will be much help but I found this to be a useful tutorial when putting together a custom membership provider recently.

http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

I have found this link very useful.
writer has wonderful explanation to Custom membership provider.
Relay helpful,

http://thekfactor.info/articles

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.